# Alternating series of primes

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Consider the infinite alternating series:
$2-3+5-7+11-13+17...$ taken over all primes.
Partial sums at odd terms gives:
$$2-3+5=2^2\\
2-3+5-7+11=2^3\\
2-3+5-7+11-13+\dotsb+23=2^4\\
\vdots$$
Is there a proof that there are infinite partial sums that give as a result a number of the form $2^{k}$?

Comment: Interesting discovery...

Comment: Welcome to MSE, as advice I would like to add that for some questions is better add more tags, and see the tutorial of tex from the Meta site. Good luck

Comment: Are some powers of 2 missing in the sequence?

Comment: Add the first term =2

Comment: Following user355705 you have -2+3+5-7.... --103+107  = 62, but -2+3+5-7.... -109+113 = 66. Perhaps For the smaller prime numbers, the reason is because the differences between consecutive primes is either 2 or 4? But as you go along the sequence you get differences like 6, 10.

Comment: Some insights are available on [A008347](https://oeis.org/A008347) from OEIS.

Comment: There's a conjecture that $512$ is the largest power of two for some number of terms in the series, but not a proof.

Comment: I checked for the first $5\cdot 10^7$ primes and did not find a power of two bigger than $512$.

Comment: Well, it remains to prove that by denoting by $(p_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ the $n^{\text{th}}$ prime number, $$\sum_{n=1}^{2^k + 1}p_n(-1)^{n+1} = 2^{k+1}.$$

Comment: If true, wouldn't that mean that given the first $n-1$ prime numbers you could determine the $nth$?

Comment: @user477343 instead when you take partial sums at even terms you get -3,-5,-7,-19,-29-37 which seems to be primes with primitive root of 2.

Comment: @EnzoCreti I see.... I find this problem quite interesting.

Comment: @John Could you please provide a reference for that conjecture? I can't find one anywhere

Comment: @EnzoCreti It's in the documentation of the series on OEIS. The person posting the conjecture (actually, several conjectures) has a homepage that you can reach out to. (It's conjecture (iii) near the top.)

Comment: @orlp Surely the partial sums do not stop at $2^{512}$ since the sequence is increasing...

Comment: @Pickle  I never claimed that.

Comment: @orlp Then I did not understand your comment correctly. If all partial sums have the form $2^k$ for some positive integer $k$, and moreover no $k$ was found that is greater than $512$ among the first $5\times10^7$ primes, then what value does the $513^{\rm th}$ partial sum have? Surely it must be above $2^{512}$, or am I missing something?

Comment: @Pickle What makes you think that all partial sums have the form $2^k$? $2-3+5-7+11-13+17 = 12$.

Comment: @orlp That's what I thought. But then I saw that other users here in the comments section already concluded that they add up to $2^k$. If this is not the case I should feel ashamed for being so gullible...:)

Comment: The above is actually not coincidental nor is it a pattern. It is only sighted due to small prime gaps for small primes. In fact, it is not hard to show that $ 64 = 2^6 $ cannot be expressed like above. This is due to the fact that over a period of two, $A008347$ is strictly increasing.

Comment: @EnzoCreti I thank you for the observation you've made.

Comment: I checked primes up to $10^{10}$ and found no hit beyond 512. The code is here: https://ideone.com/JmTtO0. On my i7 machine, it runs for 13 minutes.

Comment: Isn't this an open question?

Answer (score 6):

Effectively you are accumulating alternate prime gaps. $2+(5-3) + (11-7)+(17-13)+ \cdots $. The downstep values are irrelevant because they are odd. The alternating even values are monotonically increasing.

Prime gaps are fairly small compared to the primes themselves but are very difficult to put strict limits on analytically. I would not be surprised to continue to find occasional hits on powers of two indefinitely, but they evidently become rarer.

Tabulating the results for primes out to $500$ million for the increasing power of two, the prime $p_k$ where the series reaches that value and the actual series value $S_k$ at that point:

\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\text{power of $2$} & p_k & S_k & \text{hit?} \\ \hline
2 & 2 & 2 & \checkmark \\
4 & 5 & 4 & \checkmark \\
8 & 11 & 8 & \checkmark \\
16 & 23 & 16 & \checkmark \\
32 & 59 & 32 & \checkmark \\
64 & 127 & 70 &  \times \\
128 & 211 & 128 & \checkmark \\
256 & 449 & 258 & \times \\
512 & 977 & 512 & \checkmark \\
1024 & 2087 & 1026 & \times \\
2048 & 4091 & 2052 & \times \\
4096 & 8329 & 4104 & \times \\
8192 & 16649 & 8194 & \times \\
16384 & 33107 & 16386 & \times \\
32768 & 64997 & 32788 & \times \\
65536 & 131009 & 65556 & \times \\
131072 & 264949 & 131084 & \times \\
262144 & 525359 & 262148 & \times \\
524288 & 1051747 & 524306 & \times \\
1048576 & 2107319 & 1048594 & \times \\
2097152 & 4204223 & 2097198 & \times \\
4194304 & 8408747 & 4194312 & \times \\
8388608 & 16780681 & 8388614 & \times \\
16777216 & 33563741 & 16777218 & \times \\
33554432 & 67113811 & 33554438 & \times \\
67108864 & 134255887 & 67108866 & \times \\
134217728 & 268466503 & 134217778 & \times \\
\end{array}

Comment: Why is $p_k\approx S_k\times 2$?

Comment: Proof by induction? Inductive step: suppose $S_{k-1}\approx-p_{k-1}/2$. Then $S_k=S_{k-1}+p_k\approx-p_{k-1}/2+p_k\approx-p_k/2+p_k=p_k/2$.

Comment: @ZiruiWang I'd say that's because you're only adding every other  prime gap, not every prime gap.

Comment: $S_k$ seems to always be near a power of $2$. Why?

Comment: @user477343 that's how the $k$ is being chosen in each case, the value that takes $S_k$ to or past the next power of $2$.